# SSRS BIDS clustered stacked bar chart

Tags: charts, reporting-services, bids

Is there a way to create a chart in BIDS that combines the properties of these charts

a horizontal stacked bar chart like this:
http://www.google.com/imgres?start=230&hl=en&sa=X&biw=1920&bih=1061&addh=36&tbm=isch&prmd=imvns&tbnid=0EL4x7-sHuCIyM:&imgrefurl=http://www.phplot.com/phplotdocs/ex-horizstackedbar.html&docid=iqqzU8FDMbnIAM&imgurl=http://www.phplot.com/phplotdocs/examples/horizstackedbar.png&w=800&h=500&ei=U21kUJ_3JaTq0gH2yoDACw&zoom=1&iact=hc&vpx=1172&vpy=771&dur=3864&hovh=177&hovw=284&tx=234&ty=158&sig=114547920454640352262&page=6&tbnh=134&tbnw=215&ndsp=47&ved=1t:429,r:44,s:230,i:296

and a horizontal bar chart like this:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc281302%28v=sql.105%29.aspx

to create a chart that is stacked and clustered/grouped?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Imagine you have a dataset with the following columns:
Employee, Product, Total Sales, Month

- Create a stacked column chart.
- On the Values option put Sum(Total Sales)
- On the Series Groups put Product
- On the Category groups put Month (This will be your cluster - your second image)
- On the Category groups, below Month put Employee (This will be your detail - your first image)

Comment: it groups it using the category groups, but it doesn't align the bars side by side (touching each other)